# how use Acl to limit user access

Tags: cakephp, acl

I have same login for 3 different type of users, admin/client/user, everyone has different layout and privileges but the issue is after login every one is able to access all pages. after a lot of search on Google and stack overflow i decided to use Acl.  I created tables in database via right procedure recommended by Acl given here [AccessControlList](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html). I set permission in following way. But still all type of user are accessing all pages.

```
$this->Acl->allow(
        array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => 1),
          'admins'
        );
    $this->Acl->allow(
        array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => 2),
          'clients'
        );
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ACL is overkill for what you're looking for and will make your life hell.  I would suggest just doing something custom for this case.

Comment: thanks, i have found another way to do this.